# Como ler DBF gerado no Protheus no Visual Fox Pro?

Tags: banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados, advpl

Gerei um `DBF` no `Protheus` e estou com dificuldades para abrir o arquivo no Visual FoxPro, pois não reconhece o arquivo retornando a mensagem:

> arquivo.DBF is not a table.

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe qual a versão de `DBF` que o `Protheus` e Visual FoxPro trabalham?

Obrigado.

Comment: Eu tenho quase certeza que o DBF do Protheus é propositalmente incompatível.

Comment: @bigown Acho que não...o Protheus usa libs de terceiros (ace32.dll etc) para acesso a arquivos  dbf. A empresa originalmente proprietária das libs (Advantage Database Server) hoje pertence à SAP.

Comment: Verifique se o arquivo criado é realmente no formato DBF. Se você usa localfiles=ctree, ou o proprio programa AdvPL usa um outro driver, ele pode gravar  o arquivo no disco com a extensão DBF, mas internamente ele não é um DBF.

Answer (score 0):

O formato utilizado por um arquivo DBF pode ser identificado abrindo o arquivo com um visualizador hexadecimal, verificando o valor hexadecimal do primeiro byte do arquivo. Os formatos utilizados no Protheus são:

- `0x03` ( sem campo memo ) -- FoxBASE+/Dbase III plus compatible
- `0xF5` ( campo memo com arquivo auxiliar no formato .fpt) -- FoxPro 2.x (or
  earlier)

Para ver a lista completa com outros formatos, consulte o link [dBASE Table File Format (DBF)](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000325.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

Como você gerou isso no Protheus?

O DBF que ele gera abre normalmente no Excel por exemplo.

O arquivo que você gerou está corrompido, ou o Visual FoxPro está sem o drivers corretos.

Ha lembre-se que se o DBF tiver campos Memo, você precisa copiar junto ao DBF o FPT.

Answer (score -1):

Quando criou o seu DBF no Protheus, deve ter criado um outro arquivo com extensão .vfp esse deve estar junto no VisualFoxPro, veja a [discussão:](http://computer-programming-forum.com/2-vfp/919e08de17b1fcce.htm)